# Simplest AspNetCore MVC app in Linux App Service can't connect to a SQL Server database

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

## Summary

I recently updated my Linux App Service hosted from ASP.NET Core MVC 2.2 to 3.1 and ever since my application can no longer access the SQL Server database that lives in a VM, also in Azure.

#Findings
I deployed in Linux App Service an empty ASP.NET Core MVC 3.1 app that has 2 views - one that with a result from controller with static data (`return "Hello world!"`) and one that connects to the database.

The application runs fine on my machine, however in Azure, only the "static" view works fine. When I try to get the view with the database access, I get an error 502 after a loooooong time of waiting (~ 4 min)

> 502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server. There is a problem with the page you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed. When the Web server (while acting as a gateway or proxy) contacted the upstream content server, it received an invalid response from the content server.

When I looked in the App plan, I see that CPU has hit 90+%.

I went in Azure and checked the logs and found:

> 2020-03-18T22:19:31.461251550Z       An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
> 2020-03-18T22:19:31.467998655Z System.InvalidOperationException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.
> 2020-03-18T22:19:31.468013855Z    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)   2020-03-18T22:19:31.468019355Z    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
> 2020-03-18T22:19:31.468023955Z    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)   2020-03-18T22:19:31.468028355Z    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
> 2020-03-18T22:19:31.468032555Z    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
> 2020-03-18T22:19:31.468086255Z    at testing_aspnetcore3.Controllers.GogoController.Index() in C:\work\trash\trash\testing_aspnetcore3\Controllers\GogoController.cs:line 29
> 2020-03-18T22:19:31.468093955Z    at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
> 2020-03-18T22:19:31.468098155Z    at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(Object target, Object[] parameters)
> 2020-03-18T22:19:31.468589455Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
> 2020-03-18T22:19:31.468601655Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
> 2020-03-18T22:19:31.468841055Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
> 2020-03-18T22:19:31.468852055Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
> 2020-03-18T22:19:31.468856555Z --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> 2020-03-18T22:19:31.468860855Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
> 2020-03-18T22:19:31.468865155Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
> 2020-03-18T22:19:31.468869555Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
> 2020-03-18T22:19:31.468881555Z --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> 2020-03-18T22:19:31.468885855Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
> 2020-03-18T22:19:31.468890255Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
> 2020-03-18T22:19:31.468894155Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
> 2020-03-18T22:19:31.468898155Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
> 2020-03-18T22:19:31.468901955Z --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> 2020-03-18T22:19:31.468905955Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
> 2020-03-18T22:19:31.469268156Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
> 2020-03-18T22:19:31.469314656Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> 2020-03-18T22:19:31.469324256Z    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

## Details

Here's the code to access the database:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    using (var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT top 1 * from login", conn))
    {
        conn.Open();

        using (var reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
        {
            reader.Read();

            return Ok(reader["Username"]);
        }
    }
}
```

*P.S. Problem occurs when deployed in Linux Container. Doesn't occur on Framework-dependent windows deployment, neither on windows container.*

Comment: Well, the obvious questions are - is the correct connection string being used, and does the app service have access to the DB?

Comment: About the first one - yes. I run the very same code locally and it runs fine. About if the app service has access - I believe so. Before I migrated to 3.1 everything worked fine. My database is public for the internet... (I know)

Comment: _I run the very same code locally and it runs fine_ - so is the connection string hard-coded, or does it come from a config file?

Comment: Hardcoded for the sake of the test.

Comment: I belive the 4 minute timeout is very strange. Usually AdoNet works with 30 seconds when executing queries and stuff.

Comment: It is a bit odd, as is the high CPU usage.

Comment: from the logs it appears that the execution never went beyond connection opening.

Comment: SQL VMs are affected globally:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ac0376cb-2a0e-4dc2-a52c-d986989e6801/unable-to-create-sql-database-server?forum=ssdsgetstarted

Comment: Not sure if this is the same problem - might be, might not be ... as of now a brand new application from the visual studio template works fine when it is aspnetcore 2.1 and fails when it is 3.1 to the very same database. Locally, both work just fine.

Comment: Half a year later the problem still remains.

Comment: @LIvanov do you ensure is dns on container is well configured to access db connection server? I guess some of dns problems occured in container.

Comment: Well, I am publishing an AppService with the setting of being deployed within linux container - I don't build the image myself - I let Azure do that for me. The database service I try to connect to is publicly accessible on the internet.

Comment: Have you checked if there are differences in the aspnetcore 2.1 container configuration vs the 3.1? It may be possible that the 3.1 template your are using has "outbound" traffic restrictions and the 2.1 doesn't.

Comment: The error message doesn't say the exact problem. I would try to isolate the rot cause by running a SQL server container in the same app service as the .net core application. That way you would know if its the .net core upgrade or some network thing that's preventing the root cause to surface up. You can use a multi-container yaml file to run multiple containers on app service.

Comment: Have you had your hello world message ever return the connection string to you, to make sure you have the service configured correctly?

Comment: @JPortillo not sure how do I do that. I let azure wrap my code in container (be it linux or windows)

Comment: @rohit I'd try to look into this.

Comment: @ArneKlein not sure I understand - the connection string is a string. I use it successfully from my local environment as well as from the same app but deployed on 2.1 aspnetcore

Comment: @LIvanov I assumed the connection string was not hardcoded but in some config file. So I figured that might be an issue.

Comment: Can you share the connection string (without your actual username and password if using SQL authorization ) ?

Comment: `Server=my-server.hosted-on-azure.com,12345;Database=my-db;Uid=my-username;Password=my-password;` As I said, connection string works fine. The very same code (not a single change, hence the same connection string) works fine when deploying on a 2.1 aspnetcore container.